# Mongoose: Array of ObjectID's with null's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have Schema with following structure:

```
//...
positions: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Story'
}]
//...
```

Now, in ideal condition, this array would contain only ids, and populating those won't make a problem.

```
let positions = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
```

But sometimes, I need to delete some id at specific position, but keep the rest at theirs indexes. So I would end up with:

```
let positions = ['id1', null, 'id3'];
```

An array like above, I can't even save to Document, and neither populate it.

How can I define Schema, so it can hold some **falsy** value, and not throw errors on saving it, and also skip those values on populating?

Comment: The things is you should have to keep indexes. And if you absoluely have to, store indexes in an other array.

Comment: Are you talking about setting a single matched element to `null` for later removal? That may indeed be a problem with a mongoose schema with types set, but just to be clear you should not "need" to do such a process unless the items in the array actually appear with the same value more than once.